# If Luke Skywalker wanted to die, then why go into exile?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, luke-skywalker, force-ghost

In *[The Last Jedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi)*, [Luke Skywalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Skywalker) tells Rey that he went into exile to die and that he wished for the Jedi to end. He tried to rebuild the Jedi Order, but that went very badly. He foresaw a pupil of his turning to the Dark Side and vowed to end the Jedi Order fearing what would happen. There was clearly a pattern of Jedi turning Dark and causing destruction across the galaxy twice in the recent past, namely Count Dooku and Anakin Skywalker.

**Since Jedi can transform themselves into Force Ghosts, why would he need to go into exile?** There was no need to hide on Ahch-To when he could have just disappeared into the Force the moment he chose to end the Jedi Order.

Please provide answers based on canon sources.

Comment: Not all Jedi can force ghost themselves, and It's certainly not easy.

Comment: @Möoz Luke was able to ghost. This isn't a question about whether some random Jedi could do it, but whether Luke could.

Comment: In the movies, the only times we've seen a Jedi transform themselves into a Force Ghost was when they were already dying or about to die.  That doesn't necessarily mean that it is a prerequisite, but is there any evidence that it isn't?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think Luke meant that he went into exile because he wanted to die, I think he meant that he went into exile intending to remain there for the rest of his life.

Comment: ... perhaps out-of-universe that line was meant as a reference to [Jeremiah 34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah+34&version=MEV)?

Comment: If he literally wanted to die he could have just killed himself - no need for force ghost.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think he wanted to die in a literal sense. When he says

> I came to this island to die

I read that as

> I came here to brood about my failures as a Jedi master

He clearly wasn't suicidal. Luke doesn't even seem depressed in the montage of day-to-day life on the island. He's very disillusioned about the Jedi, however, and even The Force. He makes it clear to Rey he does not want to train Jedi.

Most importantly, Force Ghosting would have meant reconnecting to the thing that he was escaping from. It likely would have meant facing Yoda and Obi-Wan Kenobi (which he did after reconnecting). So Luke prefers to live his remaining days as a normal hermit, absent of any Force connections whatsoever.

Comment: Also, remember that Luke grew up on a farm. Maybe he *likes* or at least doesn't mind living out in the middle of nowhere with few friends.

Comment: @RobertColumbia TLJ needed a scene where Luke spent all his time going to town picking up power converters.